# Make a library that is statically linked

Tags: android, c, static-libraries

So , I have installed Ubuntu(but still use the Android kernel) on my Android phone with the intention of using it to compile native code for the device using the `glibc`.

I made a library, which I plan to use it in an app which I want to make, using JNI, but I am using the math library. My question is:

> Is there a way to include these libraries into the library that I
>   created so that my phone can use the glibc library instead of the
>   bionic(which is what the NDK uses) library?

NOTE: I have tried making a test program that uses the library and statically links to make sure that the compiled code would work on the android OS and not just Ubuntu, and I came to the conclusion that it does :) So any answer pertaining to my question would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ar` to extract the original `.o` files from any `.a` files:

```
ar x libm.a
```

You can then select whichever .o files you like and link them into your own code.

`.a` library files can be viewed as tar files with extra symbol-index features (although I don't know how similar the internals are).

WARNING: in general, you can only use .o files from *static* libraries in your main application. If you try to link them into a shared library (`.so` file) you may be out of luck. The `.o` file needs to have been created with `-fPIC` for that to work, and this is often not the case for static libraries.

Comment: So I can do this with official glibc libraries aswell?

Comment: Hmm, I've just added a caveat to that statement in the answer.